# How many times do I have to repeat a specific shuffle of playing cards to get back to where I started?

Tags: algorithm, math, repeat, shuffle, playing-cards

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so please excuse my mistakes if I'm doing something wrong.

---

Ok so I'm trying to find an algorithm/function/something that can calculate how many times I have to do the same type of shuffle of 52 playing cards to get back to where I started.

The specific shuffle I'm using goes like this:

-You will have two piles.

-You have the deck with the back facing up. (Lets call this pile 1)

-You will now alternate between putting a card in the back of pile 1 **Example: Let's say you have 4 cards in a pile, back facing up, going from 4 closest to the ground and 1 closest to the sky (Their order is 4,3,2,1. You take card 1 and put it beneath card 4 mening card 1 is now closest to the ground and card 4 is second closest, order is now 1,4,3,2.** and putting one in pile 2. 
-Pile 2 will "stack downwards" meaning you will always put the new card at the bottom of that pile. (Back always facing up)

-The first card will always get put at the back of pile 1.

-Repeat this process until all cards are in pile 2.

-Now take pile 2 and do the exact same thing you just did.

**My question is: How many times do I have to repeat this process until I get back where I started?**

---

Side notes:

- If this is a common way of shuffling cards and there already is a solution, please let me know.

- I'm still new to math and coding so if writing up an equation/algorithm/code for this is really easy then don't laugh at me pls ;<.

- Sorry if I'm asking this at the wrong place, I don't know how all this works.

- English isn't my main language and I'm not a native speaker either so please excuse any bad grammar and/or other grammatical errors.

I do however have a code that does all of this ([Link here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/341500478/editor)) but I'm unsure if it's the most effective way to do it, and it hasn't given a result yet so I don't even know if it works. If you wan't to give tips or suggestions on how to change it then please do, I would really appreciate it. It's done in scratch however because I can't write in any other languages... sorry...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "You will now alternate between putting a card at the back of pile 1 and putting one in pile 2." This is unclear, since you said pile 1 has the back facing up; so if you put one at the "back", wouldn't this just be the next card that goes to pile 2? Perhaps you could illustrate your shuffling algorithm with an example, say with 8 cards?

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this now, I'll update it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: If you can code this shuffle, do it, and then repeat it until the current mixed stack of cards matches the original one. You'll get the answer

Comment: You might have to run the algorithm upwards of 50,000 times to get back to the original state. That's probably feasible, but there is an efficient way using group theory which doesn't require performing the shuffle more than once.

Comment: I linked a code example I did in scratch, this was running for almost half an hour with no result. Maybe the code is just too slow. Once i got up to 40k shuffles, however I'm not sure if the code was even properly setup then.

Comment: Thanks, i'll search it up and see what I find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any fixed shuffle is equivalent to a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition); what you want to know is the [order of that permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutation_order). This can be computed by decomposing the permutation into [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) and then computing the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the cycle lengths.

---

I'm not able to properly understand your algorithm, but here's an example of shuffling 8 elements and then finding the number of times that shuffle needs to be repeated to get back to an unshuffled state.

Suppose the sequence starts as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and after one shuffle, it's 3,1,4,5,2,8,7,6.

- The number 1 goes to position 2, then 2 goes to position 5, then 5 goes to position 4, then 4 goes to position 3, then 3 goes to position 1. So the first cycle is (1 2 5 4 3).
- The number 6 goes to position 8, then 8 goes to position 6. So the next cycle is (6 8).
- The number 7 stays in position 7, so this is a trivial cycle (7).

The lengths of the cycles are 5, 2 and 1, so the least common multiple is 10. This shuffle takes 10 iterations to get back to the intitial state.

---

If you don't mind sitting down with pen and paper for a while, you should be able to follow this procedure for your own shuffling algorithm.

Comment: I'm somewhat getting your point. So basically let's number the cards like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. (Using 8 so it's easier to read and write.)
First 1 goes to position 8 (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1)
then 2 goes to a separate pile (3,4,5,6,7,8,1)(2)
then 3 goes to position 7 (4,5,6,7,8,1,3)(2)
then 4 goes to the separate pile, behind the 2 (5,6,7,8,1,3)(2,4)
then 5 goes to position 6 (6,7,8,1,3,5)(2,4)
then 6 goes to the separate pile (7,8,1,3,5)(2,4,6)
etc etc. until 1 goes to the separate pile completing the shuffle (2,4,6,8,1,3,7,5,1)

Comment: In that case the cycles are (1 8 4 2) and (3 5 7 6), so the lengths are 4 and 4 and the LCM is 4.

Comment: Oh now i see. Putting one away and putting one in the back are two different cycles. I'll try to follow this with 52 cards and see what I get. Thanks! :)

Comment: I think you're confusing the cycles with steps in the shuffle definition.  Forget the mechanics; jump to the point where the first shuffle is done.   The permutation function for a single shuffle is `12345678` => `24683751`.  A `cycle` follows one card through the minimum number of shuffles to return to its original position.  Trace card 1 as it moves to position 8 on the first shuffle, then 4, 2, and back to 1 after four shuffles.  This means that cards `1, 2, 4, 8` are in a cycle of length 4.  Similarly, `3, 5, 7, 6` are also in a cycle of length 4.  Each is "home" in exactly 4 shuffles.

Comment: This was a better explanation, thank you. I wasn't really getting how they got 1843 and 3576 in the beginning but now I do. Thanks again :)

Comment: Ran a new code, it gave me the answer 840. I tried to recreate the 839th shuffle it gave me and do the last shuffle irl but this gave me a different result. Maybe the result differs because I'm tired, hope it's not the code. https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/342248506/editor/
this code is much simpler and shorter, no idea why I didn't use this earlier.